# How to fix SVG drop shadow clipping problem

Tags: html, css, svg

[image: drop shadow clipping problem]

check the image

I am applying drop shadow with filter from css

```
.bulb-glass-active {
  fill: #d3a226 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 25px #ffb800);
}
```

and this is the path code

```
        <path
          class="bulb-glass"
          style="fill: #212225"
          d="M394.278,138.286C394.278,61.911,332.363,0,255.988,0S117.702,61.911,117.702,138.286
    c0,31.58,10.607,60.671,28.421,83.951h-0.024c23.22,31.214,61.983,84.477,61.983,145.196h47.905h47.909
    c0-60.719,38.763-113.978,61.983-145.196h-0.028C383.671,198.957,394.278,169.865,394.278,138.286z"
        />
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: can you provide more code then just css?

Comment: okay i also added path code.

Comment: and what exacly seems to be the problem?

Comment: exacly same at the picture

Comment: try describing it. Like the drop-shadow is overlapping or the picture is displaced?

Comment: The shadow is falling outside the svg canvas. Please try using a viewBox attribute for the svg element. Please try `viewBox="0 -50 500 500"` . Also: if the svg element have a width and a height use only the width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be different options. Here I use `transform="translate(0 50)"` to move the path on the y-axis. I also set the viewbox on the `<svg>` to control the inner sizes of the SVG.

```css
.bulb-glass-active {
  fill: #d3a226 !important;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 25px #ffb800);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 500 500" width="300">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500" fill="black"/>
  <path transform="translate(0 50)" class="bulb-glass bulb-glass-active" style="fill: #212225"
    d="M394.278,138.286C394.278,61.911,332.363,0,255.988,0S117.702,61.911,117.702,138.286
    c0,31.58,10.607,60.671,28.421,83.951h-0.024c23.22,31.214,61.983,84.477,61.983,145.196h47.905h47.909
    c0-60.719,38.763-113.978,61.983-145.196h-0.028C383.671,198.957,394.278,169.865,394.278,138.286z"/>
</svg>
```